# Delete items from an array of objects if they have the same key value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter, reduce

I am struggling to get this thing working. I have an array of objects like this:

```js
let myCities = [
  {
    value: 'Barcelona',
    code: 02342837492482347
  },
  {
    value: 'Rome',
    code: 28282716171819
  },
  {
    value: 'Barcelona',
    code: 67246726482
  },
  {
    value: 'Paris',
    code: 12319808080
  },  
]
```

I would like to delete all the items that the key `value` is the same but keep the 1st one. So I'll have a result like this:

```js
let myCities = [
  {
    value: 'Barcelona',
    code: 02342837492482347
  },
  {
    value: 'Rome',
    code: 28282716171819
  },
  {
    value: 'Paris',
    code: 12319808080
  },  
]
```

Any solutions that comes to your mind?
Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at [lodash uniqBy](https://lodash.com/docs/#uniqBy)

Comment: Please show any attempt you have made so far that is not working.  You are expected already have made one

Comment: hey @Marc89, any updates on this?

Answer (score 0):

I have two!

For one, you could temporarily use an Object with the value of the city as key and the `code` as value. Then iterating over `myCities` using `forEach()` and populating the Object. Once done, map that object back to an Array using `Object.keys(tempObj).map()`.

Second idea would be going straight with a [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and create the second Array from `myCities`. Its third argument contains the input array (= `myCities`). But even here you would need some kind of bookkeeping …

Answer (score 0):

You can try [underscore js](http://underscorejs.org/#uniq)

```js
let myCities = [
  {
    value: 'Barcelona',
    code: 02342837492482347
  },
  {
    value: 'Rome',
    code: 28282716171819
  },
  {
    value: 'Barcelona',
    code: 67246726482
  },
  {
    value: 'Paris',
    code: 12319808080
  },  
]

console.log(_.uniq(myCities, x => x.value));
```

```html
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myCities = [
  {
    value: 'Barcelona',
    code: 02342837492482347
  },
  {
    value: 'Rome',
    code: 28282716171819
  },
  {
    value: 'Barcelona',
    code: 67246726482
  },
  {
    value: 'Paris',
    code: 12319808080
  },  
];
    var arr = []; var res = [];
    for(var i = 0; i<myCities.length;i++){
      if(!arr.includes(myCities[i].value)){
        res.push(myCities[i]);
        arr.push(myCities[i].value);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
let myCities = [
      {
        value: 'Barcelona',
        code: 02342837492482347
      },
      {
        value: 'Rome',
        code: 28282716171819
      },
      {
        value: 'Barcelona',
        code: 67246726482
      },
      {
        value: 'Paris',
        code: 12319808080
      },  
    ]

    function uniqueByKey(objArr) {
      let tmp = {};
      for(let i = 0; i < objArr.length; i++) {
         let elem = objArr[i];
         if(typeof tmp[elem.value] === "undefined") {
          tmp[elem.value] = true;
          continue;
         }
         objArr.splice(i, 1)
         i--;
      }
    }

    uniqueByKey(myCities)
    console.log(JSON.stringify(myCities));
```

Comment: what's wrong with my answer? please, i really cannot figure out.